# AngularJS not compiling consistently

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am working on a dynamic editable table directive, and half of the time when i refresh my page, the angular components are resolved to the values of their variables, and half the time it is rendering literally {{ variable }} on the page.  Here is a plunker of the issue:

http://plnkr.co/edit/WvzKYQ?p=preview

```
angular.module('myApp').directive('hmGrid', function ($window) {
   ...
   link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
   ...
   controller: function ($scope) { 
   ...
});
```

I have a feeling that the code in my link and controller, (in my directive) are not following proper programming practices, and so is not compiling by the time the page renders. Can someone please help re-organize the code so that it renders successfully every time?

Comment: check console errors - i.e. your plunk has some

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try moving your code that initializes your `gridoptions` into the controller for your directive, instead of initializing gridoptions in a separate controller, then passing them to your directive:

```
controller: function ($scope, $http) { 
            $http.get('filename.txt').
            success(function(data) {
              $scope.data = data.data;
              $scope.headers = data.headers;
              $scope.headernames = data.headernames;
              $scope.gridShowing = true;
              $scope.editShowing = false;
              $scope.addShowing = false;
              $scope.idx = 0;

              $scope.reversed = false;
              $scope.sortColumn = '';
            });
```

Then you can remove the `gridoptions` attribute from your directive, remove the unnecessary extra controller, and your directive should work every time.

Updated plunker [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/w7bu13HrwwXTFD1IVIlx?p=preview).

Comment: You should really break your $http call outside of the controller and into a Service like so: http://plnkr.co/edit/UvPAqGrk9x1eOBp1OuNw?p=preview

Comment: Andrew, the only thing is, I want to be able to use this directive on any JSON, so being locked into the same JSON will limit the flexibility of this directive, is their a way of maybe passing in the service path?

Comment: Nevermind, It looks like Shane already answered this question.  Thanks Shane.

Comment: Shane, instead of declaring it in the factory, Is it possible to allow the user of this directive to specify the path to the JSON as an attribute to the <hm-grid>